# how to convert minutes into microtime

Tags: php, time, yii, microtime

I have a session which contains `microtime(true)` value. like below:

```
Yii::app()->user->setState('portal_logged_time', microtime(true));
```

Now i want to add 15 minutes in above session, but it should remain in microtime.

```
$starttime = Yii::app()->user->getState('portal_logged_time');
// Now i want to add microtime of 15 minutes into $starttime
$endtime = // i want to do something like this ($starttime*15*60);
```

I have tried this but it is not working `$starttime*15*60`.

So how to achieve that?

After that i am trying to fetch remaining minutes and seconds:

```
$duration = $endtime-$starttime;

$hours = (int)($duration/60/60);
$minutes = (int)($duration/60)-$hours*60;
$seconds = (int)$duration-$hours*60*60-$minutes*60;
```

Comment: Better question. Why microtime?

Comment: Good question, but didn't thought about it, i just used it.

Comment: Can you, you know, unuse it and just use seconds from `time()`?

Comment: yes, going to change that.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with using `microtime(true)`?

Comment: @PEMapModder, But after that i have to fetch remaining  minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Values provided by `microtime()` are in seconds. So you should simply do:

```
$endtime = $starttime + 15*60;
```

Comment: i used microtime(true) so it returns the floating value. so after that if i want to convert them into minutes, seconds then it will create problem.

Comment: I don't understand at all your issue. What do you want to do exactly? Which problem do you expect?

Comment: You should open another StackOverflow question for that... Try `$duration = $endtime - microtime(true);` instead of `$duration = $endtime-$starttime;` (I suppose that `$endtime` contains the timestamp corresponding to the instant the session will expire)

Answer (score 2):

> Note that the timestamp returned is "with microseconds", not "in microseconds". This is especially good to know if you pass 'true' as the parameter and then calculate the difference between two float values -- the result is already in seconds; it doesn't need to be divided by a million.

```
<?php

$temp = microtime(true);
echo "$temp";

echo "<br>";

echo date('Y-m-d h i s', $temp);

$sum = round($temp) + 900;

echo "<br>";
echo date('Y-m-d h i s', $sum);

?>
```

[Check here](https://eval.in/640937)

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
echo date("H:i:s",$endtime-$starttime);
```

Manually :

```
$duration = $endtime-$starttime;
$hours = (int)($duration/60/60);
$minutes = (int)($duration/60)-$hours*60;
$seconds = (int)$duration-$hours*60*60-$minutes*60;
```

Comment: i want to  add 15 minutes worth of microtime(true) in $starttime variable. I am not sure how your answer address my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`$starttime = round(microtime(true) * 1000);`

`$endtime = $starttime + 15*60*1000;`

Comment: what is the reason behind *1000 in starttime?

Comment: seconds to millisecond